# Hibernate equivalent properties for these openjpa propertie

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, nhibernate-mapping, openjpa

I have an requirement to use Hibernate Persistence instead of OpenJPA Persistence 
I searched in google but didn't get information still looking on it.Any body help on this. I am not much expert in Hibernate.

```
 <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed"/>
    <property name="openjpa.ConnectionRetainMode" value="always"/>
```